# Moving MySQL Record to Other Table after Timeframe

Tags: mysql, events, triggers, timestamp, scheduler

I am trying to find the best way to process a record with a timestamp field whereby it would automatically move from one table to another table after 30 minutes.

Comment: You need to schedule a job to accomplish this.  However, your application probably does not require this functionality and there are undoubtedly better ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please let us know about that as well so that we can help you out more relevantly.

Comment: Just trying to find the best and most efficient way. Basically I need a record updatable by users, and then 30 minutes after submitted, lock the record for updating or move to another table to query on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `MySQL 5.1.6` and later, check out [MySQL events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html).

Events work the same with other routines, you can `CREATE`, `ALTER`, and even `DROP` them.

Martin Psinas has [basic examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-mysql-events/) of this. (Just found online, we're not friends, lol)

First, you'll have to enable events scheduler:

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Then, you can create your event like (base from your question):

```
CREATE EVENT ProcessRecord
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 MINUTE
    --STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    --ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    DO
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ...
            SELECT ...
      END
```

Otherwise, you can go with windows scheduled tasks, if you're using windows platform.